# Fonts with - Webpack with postcss

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, webpack

Seems like I'm having a lot of problems recently with webpack :) But here goes another one for you guys:

**Folder Structure**

[image]

**CSS**

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'LatoBlack';
    src: url('/font/Lato-Black.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('/font/Lato-Black.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('/font/Lato-Black.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('/font/Lato-Black.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('/font/Lato-Black.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

**Webpack Config**

```
'use strict';
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var qs = require('querystring');
var font = require('postcss-font-magician')({
    hosted: '/public/fonts'
});
var precss = require('precss');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var stripInlineComments = require('postcss-strip-inline-comments');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    // resolve: { modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'], extension: ['', '.js', '.css'] },
    entry: [
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
        path.join(__dirname, 'src/client/js/Kindred')
        // path.join(__dirname, 'app/main')
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/public/'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'app/index.tpl.html',
            inject: 'body',
            filename: 'index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0", "react-hmre"]
            }
        }, {
            test: /\.json?$/,
            loader: 'json'
        },
            {test: /\.jpg$/, loader: "file-loader"},
            // Font Definitions
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader?importLoaders&' + qs.stringify({
                        modules: true,
                        importLoaders: 1,
                        localIdentName: '[path][name]-[local]'
                    }),
                    'postcss-loader?parser=postcss-scss'
                ]
            },
            { test: /.(png|woff(2)?|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=\.]+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }            
        ]
    },
    postcss: function (webpack) {
        return [
            stripInlineComments
            , require('postcss-fontpath' , {checkPath: true})
            , font
            , precss
            , autoprefixer
            , require('postcss-simple-vars')
            , require('postcss-nested'
                , autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 versions']}))
        ];
    }
};
```

**Error Messages**

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?importLoaders&modules=true&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=%5Bpath%5D%5Bname%5D-%5Blocal%5D!./~/postcss-loader?parser=postcss-scss!./src/client/scss/main.css
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../../../client/font/fontello.eot in C:\var\www\webpack-express-boilerplate\src\client\scss
 @ ./~/css-loader?importLoaders&modules=true&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=%5Bpath%5D%5Bname%5D-%5Blocal%5D!./~/postcss-loader?parser=postcss-scss!./src/client/scss/main.css 6:876-929 6:955-1008
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having trouble loading in fonts with webpack

Comment: Let me know if my answer helps at all. I might be able to help trouble shoot as well

Comment: Haha yeah it does.. it turns out that my issue was with a small typo in my webpack config. The file loader's include path did not exist, yet the errors I were getting had nothing to do with the folder not existing.. just saying "undefined" something. I appreciate you posting out the answer though.. it's still very helpful!

Comment: :D they are like a black hole, errors flying everywhere and no idea what they mean lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok just so its easy for people to see what I did to get it working here it is:

I think it was easier for me to completely remove scss and just go with css modules out of the box. This seemed to help a lot.

I used git@github.com:christianalfoni/webpack-express-boilerplate.git to help me guide myself through. Knowing I had a working thing actually taught me a hell of a lot more than I have most likely learnt before hand in webpack. As you can guess that wasn't very much :D

Also the one main change that really helped was changing the paths not surprisingly. But these were relative to the path sex in `output.path` I had read this before but thought that was relative to the `wepack.config.js` not that from there on everything would count as document root, even for the html and css.

**KEY PART :) **

I also have to update my express set up, as I hadn't given it a `express.static` path... Oh my folly, how could I miss such a basic thing.. So:

**Express**

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/')); //Don't forget me :(
```

**Final CSS**

```
/* Webfont: Lato-Black */@font-face {
    font-family: 'LatoBlack';
    src: url('/font/Lato-Black.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('/font/Lato-Black.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('/font/Lato-Black.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('/font/Lato-Black.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('/font/Lato-Black.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

**Wekpack.config**

```
'use strict';
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var qs = require('querystring');
var precss = require('precss');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var stripInlineComments = require('postcss-strip-inline-comments');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    // resolve: { modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'], extension: ['', '.js', '.css'] },
    entry: [
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
        path.join(__dirname, 'src/client/js/Kindred')
        // path.join(__dirname, 'app/main')
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/public/'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'public/index.tpl.html',
            inject: 'body',
            filename: 'index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {"presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0", "react-hmre"]}
            }, {
                test: /\.json?$/,
                loader: 'json'
            },
            {
                test: /\.jpg$/, loader: "file-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader?importLoaders&' + qs.stringify({
                        modules: true,
                        importLoaders: 1,
                        localIdentName: '[path][name]-[local]'
                    }),
                    'postcss-loader?parser=postcss-scss'
                ]
            },
            // Font Definitions
            { test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=image/svg+xml&name=font/[name].[ext]' },
            { test: /\.woff$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=font/[name].[ext]' },
            { test: /\.woff2$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff2&name=font/[name].[ext]' },
            { test: /\.[ot]tf$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=font/[name].[ext]' },
            { test: /\.eot$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/vnd.ms-fontobject&name=font/[name].[ext]' }
        ]
    },
    postcss: function (webpack) {
        return [
            stripInlineComments
            , precss
            , autoprefixer
            , require('postcss-simple-vars')
            , require('postcss-nested'
            , autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 versions']}))
        ];
    }
};
```

I have also posted this answer one another question. They were all very closely related, yet different problems. So i think its ok to do post this again.

I want to say sorry for everybody that tried. I feel that I was far off in the end. I am only posting this incase anybody is having similar problems. What I would take from this is just to either use that boiler plate. Or the static part and parths inside of the html because of that.